# How do I get the value of the aria-label attribute from this WebElement?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, dom, selenium-chromedriver

Using Java Selenium, I have a reference to a `WebElement` object that represents the following HTML node:

```
<td role="gridcell" class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" style="width: 25%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;" tabindex="-1" data-mat-row="0" data-mat-col="0" aria-label="2001" aria-selected="false">...</td>
```

I need the *2001* value of the `aria-label` attribute, but I can't seem to able to. The following method invocations all return `null` and I don't know why:

- `element.getAttribute("aria-label");`
- `element.getAttribute("ariaLabel");`
- `element.getDomAttribute("aria-label");`
- `element.getDomAttribute("ariaLabel");`
- `element.getDomProperty("aria-label");`
- `element.getDomProperty("ariaLabel");`

The reason for trying both `aria-label` and `ariaLabel` is that it's listed as `ariaLabel` in the properties list:

[image: td properties]

I printed out the values of all other attributes of this node to verify that it's not a timing issue, and, curiously, this was the output:

```
role: gridcell
class: mat-calendar-body-cell-container ng-star-inserted
style: width: 25%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;
tabindex: null
data-mat-row: 0
data-mat-col: 0
aria-label: null
aria-selected: null
```

How can I get the value of `aria-label`?

Selenium version: **4.15.0**

Chromedriver version: **122.0.6261.57**

Answer (score 0):

The website version I was automating against had been updated to move the `aria-label` attribute from the `td` node to a child `button` node; I just hadn't bothered refreshing the page yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you listed first , this should work: element.getAttribute("aria-label");